# How to Merge Tables and prevent IDs clashing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I want to merge the IndirectFlights table to the PriceTable. 
I do not have IDs entered in the SourceTable (IndirectFlights) and I haven't set a PK for it yet.
The ID column for the PriceTable is an Identity (1,1) column and is also the Primary Key.

Qs1 How do I enter IDs in Source column so that they dont clash with target table (PriceTable) IDs? I was thinking of using a sequence but It potentially could clash in future.
Qs2 Can I choose what columns to merge or must I merge all the columns from the Source table?

```
Target Table (PriceTable) Columns
IDAirport_ICAO_Code,Airline_ICAO_Code,Departure,Price,RouteStatus,DateRowModified

Source Table (IndirectFlights) Columns
IDAirport_ICAO_Code,Destination,Airline,Airline_ICAO_Code,RouteStatus,Connecting Airport
```

**Edit:** I have just run the following Union All statement as an alternative to using Merge.

```
Select ID,Airport_ICAO_Code,Airline_ICAO_Code,RouteStatus
From RoughworkPriceTable
Union All
Select ID,Airport_ICAO_Code,Airline_ICAO_Code,RouteStatus
From RoughworkIndirectFlights;
```

The code worked but i noticed that the ID column accepted the Null values from IndirectFlights.ID eventhough I have the ID columns set to Not Null.

Can anyone explain this. 
Also can someone expalin how I could create a new permanent table from this Union All statement.

Comment: What database are you using - MS SQL Server? Is the merge a one off, or must it be repeated?

Comment: if you need to frequently merge them, look at having an uniqueidentifier as the primary key, risk of collision is nearly non existant.

Comment: Im using Server express 2014. The Merge is a one off but I possibly would be merging the tables again depending on whether new values are entered into the IndirectFlights table.

Comment: how would the uniqueidentiifer key for the Indirectflights table be compatible with the Identity Column in the PriceTable

Comment: you could use Identity(-1,-1) ? that way you would avoid future clashes. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473215/negative-primary-keys

Comment: thanks Jon. I hadnt thought of that. Do you know if i can merge specific columns or do i have to merge whole table.

Comment: I found a helpful post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620645/merging-two-tables-duplicate-keys. It advises setting a large range on the Source table, like setting it to IDENTITY(2000000000, 1). It advises against Uniqueidentifiers though,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new table with something like

```
     Select * into newTmpTable from (
        Select ID,Airport_ICAO_Code,Airline_ICAO_Code,RouteStatus From RoughworkPriceTable 
    Union All 
    Select ID,Airport_ICAO_Code,Airline_ICAO_Code,RouteStatus From RoughworkIndirectFlights) 
as mergedData;
```

Comment: Thanks very much for helping out Jon. I do forget how useful the Select Into statements are.